# Web page won't show up when I run a Dockerized Django project

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to Dockerize a Django project but the webpage won't show up when I run the container. However, I don't get any errors in the terminal when I run `docker compose up --build`. I've confirmed on Docker Desktop that my container is present and running.

The error I get is ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID which says the site can't be reached.

Here is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I tried adding the "0.0.0.0:8000" to CMD but that didn't work either.

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

And lastly here is my requirements.txt file:

```
asgiref==3.6.0
Django==4.2.1
djangorestframework==3.14.0
psycopg2==2.9.6
pytz==2023.3
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2023.3
```

After looking up the problem online and on YouTube, I'm not sure what the problem is because it seems like I have everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough information to see what's wrong.

But make sure That you are following all these steps:

1. Check the container logs: Use the `docker logs` command to check the logs of your container and make sure it's starting up correctly
2. check if there is any fire wall blocking the port `ufw status` and allow the port `ufw allow 8000`
3. Check Django settings: Make sure that your Django settings are configured correctly. Specifically, check that your ALLOWED_HOSTS setting includes the domain or IP address you're trying to access the app from. You should also check the SSL and security settings if you have HTTPS enabled.

You can find the full options in django settings here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/

Comment: Okay, I checked the logs and no error is popping up. The only thing it says is that I have 18 unapplied migrations, but that same message pops up when I successfully run the Django project outside of Docker. I also enabled port 8000 using the command you outlined. I also set ALLOWED_HOSTS to be "*" which I know is bad practice but for the sake of trying to fix this current problem, I'm setting it to allow any port.

However, the problem still isn't fixed, do you have any other idea what might be wrong?

Comment: are you using any webservers  as your reverse proxy? or directly from ip?

Comment: I'm directly using the IP.

Comment: pretty sure you are missing something, check the ports again, check the container again, check docker again, check settings again.